# AutoMapper different level

Tags: automapper

Trying to map from Customer to CustomerDto but having issues with that extra layer in the source (I have no control over the source so I cannot align the two unfortunately).

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressSet AddressSet { get; set; }
}

public class AddressSet
{
    public AddressSetResults[] AddressSetResults { get; set; }    
}

public class AddressSetResults
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressDto AddressDto { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDto
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The following does not work for the AddressDto, any idea what I'm missing?

```
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.AddressDto , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressSet.AddressSetResults))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

#### 1) Missing map from AddressSetResults to AddressDto

In order to map inner address you need to create map for these inner types as well:

```cs
CreateMap<AddressSetResults, AddressDto>();
```

---

#### 2) Map from an element of AddressSetResults array, not from the array itself

This method:

```cs
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.AddressDto, 
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressSet.AddressSetResults))
```

tells AutoMapper to map to `AddressDto` from `AddressSetResults` which is an array of `AddressSetResults`. This is incorrect, as AutoMapper will not know how to map from array of elements to just one element. Unless you create a map for that too, which would not be a good solution.

Assuming that `AddressSetResults` will contain up to one address you can fix that adding just one more call `FirstOrDefault()` to the end of mapping expression:

```cs
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.AddressDto, 
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressSet.AddressSetResults.FirstOrDefault()))
```

`FirstOrDefault()` needs `System.Linq` namespace.

Why not just `First()`? If source `AddressSetResults` array would contain no elements, then mapping would fail resulting in exception as no elements would be found to satisfy the `First()` method call. Making it resistant to no elements scenario with `FirstOrDefault()` is more secure solution.

---

#### Final, working configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.AddressDto,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressSet.AddressSetResults.FirstOrDefault()));
CreateMap<AddressSetResults, AddressDto>();
```